# Find a specific object in many different arrays

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

If I have 10 children (objects), and each child goes to a different school (array), and wheres a different shirt (value in object). What would be the best way to find a specific child based on the shirt color?

Right now, I do this, which seems a bit long:

```
      Match *match; 
      match.match_id = @"The match id i want to find": 

      //Check array 1 for the object
      for (Match *tempMatch in matchesGrouped)
         {
             if (tempMatch.match_id == match.match_id)
             {
                 match = tempMatch; 
                 matchFound = YES; 
                 break; 
             }
         }

      //Check array 2 for the object
      for (Match *tempMatch in matchesSingle)
         {
             if (tempMatch.match_id == match.match_id)
             {
                 match = tempMatch; 
                 matchFound = YES; 
                 break; 
             }
         }

       etc for the rest of the arrays...
```

match_id is an unique integer for each match.

Thanks in advance

EDIT:

The match looks like this:

```
@interface Match : UIViewController <NSCoding> 
{

}

//Match
@property (nonatomic) int match_id; 
@property (nonatomic) int matchStatus; 
@property (nonatomic) int numberOfPlayers; 
etc...
```

Comment: Are your 10 children objects in an array? Is shirt or shirt color a property of the children objects? It would be helpful to see the code for your children objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like this example:

```
- (IBAction)buttonArrayInArrayPressed:(id)sender 
{
    NSString *item = @"a2item2";
    NSArray *a1 = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"a1item1",@"a1item2",@"a1item3", nil];
    NSArray *a2 = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"a2item1",@"a2item2",@"a2item3", nil];
    NSArray *ax = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:a1, a2, nil];
    for (NSArray *outsideArray in ax)
    {
        for (NSString *myItem in outsideArray)
        {
            if ([myItem isEqualToString:item])
            {
                NSLog(@"Found item: %@", myItem);
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

use nspredicate, are those object NSDictionarys?
try this:

```
NSArray *filtered = [matchesGrouped filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(match_id == %@)", match_id]];
```

Answer (score 1):

You could create a NSMutableArray based on the objects in array #1 and then add the objects from the other arrays to it (`arrayWithArray:`, `addObjectsFromArray:`).  Once that was done, there would be a single container to search.

(A problem with what you have posted is that if the child is found in the first array, you keep searching the rest of them.)